# Find files greater than X value, sort by size, show in ls format

Tags: find, ls, sort

My assignment is: Find files (in a specific directory that is given) , show only the ones above 100 megabytes, sort them by size, print them in ls -lh format.

This is what I execute:

```
find /home/it21366 -size +10M | sort -h | ls -lh
```

This is what I get

```
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 it21366 unixusers  12K Απρ  28  2014 a.out
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 it21366 unixusers  471 Νοέ  29 10:51 askisi.sh
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 3,0K Απρ  28  2014 code.c
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 3,0K Απρ  28  2014 code.c~
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 6,2K Απρ  28  2014 CODE.txt
-rw-------+ 1 it21366 unixusers 2,0M Απρ  28  2014 core
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 it21366 unixusers   66 Δεκ   6 14:39 it21366_ex_1_1
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 it21366 unixusers  190 Δεκ   6 14:35 it21366_ex_1_4.sh
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 it21366 unixusers  190 Δεκ   6 14:27 it21366_ex_1_4.sh~
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 it21366 unixusers  546 Δεκ   5 17:46 it21366_ex_1_5
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 509K Οκτ  23  2014 java01.pdf
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 506K Οκτ  23  2014 java02.pdf
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 249K Οκτ  11 10:03 lab01_2018-19.pdf
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 1,2K Οκτ  24 16:27 MyClock.java
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers 1,3K Οκτ  30  2013 starthere.desktop
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers    3 Οκτ  24 12:45 test
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers   12 Οκτ  24 12:45 TK.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 it21366 unixusers  14K Μάι  30  2018 Untitled 1.odt
```

I can't imagine why LS seems to ignore the other methods, and simply shows the contents of the files unsorted and unfiltered.

Comment: `ls` does not use anything you're trying to pipe to it through standard input. Since its command line arguments are just the options `-lh`, it's listing the full contents of the current directory, in long format with human-optimized file sizes, in default alphanumeric sort order. You would need different options for `ls` to sort in different ways, e.g. by size, or to display the directory list unsorted.

Comment: Related: [Pipe to `ls` Not Working as Expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176999/pipe-to-ls-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Related: [Sort the output of find -exec ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140561/sort-the-output-of-find-exec-ls)

Answer (score 3):

use xargs:

```
find /home/it21366 -size +10M | xargs ls -lhsSr
```

Comment: On the assumption that there are no files named `with spaces or tabs in them`

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if the number of files is limited enough to fit in one (long) call to `ls`, would be to use `find` to find the large files and `ls -S` to do the sorting:

```
find /home/it21366 -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lS {} + 2>/dev/null
```

The `-exec ... {} +` tells `find` to replace the "found" files into the call to `ls`, fitting as many as it can. If there are too many files, you'll get multiple calls to `ls` and thus un-sorted results (they'll be sorted in groups). I also added `-type f` to restrict the matches to regular files.